# arduino with module bluetooth hc-06 show very rare character

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino-uno

I uploaded this code in my arduino uno R3

```
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>       

SoftwareSerial mySerial(0, 1);

void setup()
{
    mySerial.begin(9600);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Hello bluetooth");
}

void loop()
{
    if (mySerial.available())
        Serial.print(mySerial.read());
    if (Serial.available())
        mySerial.write(Serial.read());
    delay(100);
}
```

And then I used Blue Term(Android) to connect with the arduino and when I write something the monitor serial of arduino shows some rare characters like □□□, If i write "1" on blueterm the monitor shows 3 white squares "□□□"

The bluetooth module is a HC-06, and I wired it in this way:

```
bluetooth       arduino
TX              Pin0
RX              Pin1
Vcc             3.3v
grd             grd
```

Please help, If somebody knows why it is showing those characters?

Comment: This could well be a baud rate problem, either between the Arduino and the bluetooth module or between the computer and the Arduino (technically, it's onboard USB-serial and it's distinct processor core which are connected by an actual serial link).

Comment: So what should I do? How do I know what is the correct baud rate?

Comment: Check the docs for the bluetooth module.

Comment: I'm almost sure the baud rate is 9600, I got this link of datasheet http://silabs.org.ua/bc4/hc06.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Try to open your serial monitor and input "AT". If all is correct, it should answer "OK". If you continue to experience this problem, maybe you module has been set on a different native baud rate ( not 9600) so it cannot "read" characters correctly.
Note that if you have an HC-06 with the breakout board, you can connect it to 5v instead of 3.3V
See this link to learn how to reprogram the baud rate ( and many other stuffs ) of your hc-06:

[HC-06 AT Commands](http://www.micro4you.com/files/ElecFreaks/Bluetooth%20HC-06.pdf)